# How to get selected li value, instead of parent li value

Tags: jquery

On click of level 2 li's i want to get the particular li value.

```
<li><span class="classSpan"> Level 
      <ul>
        <li> <span class="classSpan"> Level 1 Item 1  
        <ul>
         <li><span class="classSpan">Level 2 Item 1</span</li>
         <li><span class="classSpan">Level 2 Item 2</span</li>
        </ul>
        </span> 
       </li>
      </ul>
      </span>
     </li>
```

Below event will fire 3 times instead of once(fire's for all the parents). It has to fire only once,only for selected li.

```
 $('.classSpan').click(function (e) {
   alert('click')                
  });
```

Comment: Your HTML is just plainly broken. You have missing tags, missing `<` and just ergh..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the event is bubbling/propagating up the parent. Use `e.stopPropagation()` to stop it from bubbling up and triggering additional event callbacks:

```
$('.classSpan').click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('click')                
});
```

Proof-of-concept:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.classSpan').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('click')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="classSpan">
      Level 
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span class="classSpan">
            Level 1 Item 1  
            <ul>
              <li><span class="classSpan">Level 2 Item 1</span></li>
              <li><span class="classSpan">Level 2 Item 2</span></li>
            </ul>
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Some hints:

- You might want to fix your markup: do not wrap your `<ul>` in `<span>`, but make it a sibling instead.
- Stop using `alert` for debugging: it actually halts the thread. Use `console.log()` instead, and open your developer tools.

Comment: @RajeshShetty Please accept Terry's answer if this is the one you chose.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Your span was getting all of them inside. So this was causing to click it when you click any of them.

```
<li><span class="classSpan"> Level</span>
      <ul>
        <li> <span class="classSpan"> Level 1 Item 1  </span> 
        <ul>
         <li><span class="classSpan">Level 2 Item 1</span></li>
         <li><span class="classSpan">Level 2 Item 2</span></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>

    $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.classSpan').click(function (e) {
     var x = $(this).text()
   alert(x)                
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256 DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

you need to Prevents propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.you need to stop e.stopPropagation();

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <span class="classSpan"> Level 
        <ul>
          <li>
           <span class="classSpan"> Level 1  
             <ul>
                 <li><span class="classSpan">Level 1 Item 1</span></li>
                 <li><span class="classSpan">Level 1 Item 2</span></li>
             </ul>
          </span>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Script

```
$(function() {
  $('.classSpan').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      var data = $(this).text()
     console.log(data + 'your li text get')
   });
});
```